# IBM Worklight: Installing .apk file on a real device?

Tags: android, apk, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a simple app using JQuery mobile framework (with out using any adapters). I have add android environment to generate .apk file for android mobile phones. If i install it in a device, it says "Problem in parsing the packages". Since, I am a newbie in developing mobile apps, please help me resolve the issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBM Worklight - Installing applications on a device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440824/ibm-worklight-installing-applications-on-a-device)

Comment: What is your workklight version?

Answer (score 0):

Check the minVersion in Android Manifest File  < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:maxSdkVersion="10"/>

Comment: Hi srikanth, I am using Android version 4.2.2 for development, device which i am try to install tha app having version 4.2.1. Also, I have checked the minVersion in Android Manifest file having api level '17' < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:maxSdkVersion="17"/> . Is there anything to do with this?

Comment: yes use android:minSdkVersion="10" in the Android Manifest File